# How can you define a copy constructor for a union?

Tags: c++, unions

i am trying to define a copy constructor for unions but i don't know how to do it. Does anyone know how?

Here is an example:

```
struct apple {
    string origin;
};

struct pear {
    string origin;
};

union fruit {
    fruit() {
    }

    ~fruit() {
    }

    fruit(const fruit& other) {
    }

    fruit& operator=(const fruit& rhs) {
        return *this;
    }

    apple apple;
    pear pear;
};
```

How can the assignment operator and copy constructor be solved? Thanks!

Comment: By keeping track of the actual type in a separate member, e.g. with an extra enum. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union

Comment: If you use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), you get one for free.  `std::variant` requires C++17 or later.

Comment: @PaulSanders Ah thanks, it works. Maybe eventually they'll make the default union work :)

Comment: Doubtful, `union` is a holdover from C and is generally discouraged.

Comment: @RichardBamford I don't see how they can.

Comment: `union` works perfectly fine. It's just not the tool you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using an std::variant instead works. Here is the example fixed.

```
struct apple {
    string origin;
};

struct pear {
    string origin;
};

typedef variant<apple, pear> fruit;
```